# C++ constructor of an object which is part of another object

Tags: c++, constructor

*That is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor). Please read carefully. There are two variables x (of type int and X) and one member is actually declared private, which is used in a constructor. It is about understanding the constructor process in this very specific case.*

---

I am doing a C++ course and I understand the following example that was given. It is about constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Element {
    int value;
public:

    Element(int val) {
        value = val;
        cout << "Element(" << val << ") constructed!" << endl;
    }

    int Get(void) {
        return value;
    }

    void Put(int val) {
        value = val;
    }
};

class Collection {
    Element el1, el2;
public:

    Collection(void) : el2(2), el1(1) {
        cout << "Collection constructed!" << endl;
    }

    int Get(int elno) {
        return elno == 1 ? el1.Get() : el2.Get();
    }

    int Put(int elno, int val) {
        if (elno == 1) el1.Put(val);
        else el2.Put(val);
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Collection coll;
    return 0;
}
```

Then they mentioned the following

> ...
>   We should also add that there is the following alternation for that
>   case: when the constructor is divided between the declaration and the
>   definition, the list of alternative constructors should be associated
>   with the definition, not the declaration.
>
> It means that the following snippet is correct:

```
class X {
public:
       X(int x) { };
};

class Y {
       X x;
public:
      Y(int x);
};

Y::Y(int x) : x(1) { };
```

Can someone explain? Is it really correct? And if yes, how to interpret that? `Y` has a one-parameter constructor, but no value is passed. `x(1)` is probably the constructor for the field `X x` in `Y`. Is the value of `1` (of `x(1)`) then passed to `Y(int x)` automatically although it is declared private in `Y`?

Comment: I don't agree. That is not the same. Please read again. There are two variables x (of type int and X) and one member is actually declared private, which is used in a constructor. It is about understanding the constructor process in this very specific case.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: The code snippet. Is it correct? If yes, why and how is the construction process?

Comment: Maybe he is asking about putting the constructor body in the class definition versus putting the constructor body in separate code outside the class definition.

Comment: There are plenty of questions that already exist that explain the construction process. Please ask a specific question. As for whether the code is "correct", that entirely depends on what you intended for it to do.

Comment: The constructor for Y looks correct. The construction process doesn't change between putting the constructor body in the class definition versus putting it in separate code.

Comment: It looks to me like your course material is using very confusing wording to say nothing other than "the _ctor-initialiser_ goes on the constructor _definition_ not the declaration, if the two are distinct in your program". And I have no idea what you think `private`ness has to do with it....

Comment: What may be confusing you is that  in `Y::Y(int x)` that "x" is never used. The ": x(1)" is using the member "x" defined in the class definition (X x;).

Comment: Where does the x in Y(int x) come from?

Comment: From the person who is creating an instance of Y. `Y test1(1)` will pass x as 1 (though it is never used). What you might be wanting to say in the constructor is `Y::Y(int x) : x(x) { }` which will pass the integer value x to the constructor of the X object.

Comment: @Elyasin that `x` is a bad choice for a method parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you confused about out-of-class member function definitions? Modulo inline, the second one is equivalent to `class Y{  X x; public: Y(int z) : x(1) { } };`

Comment: That was not my choice. That is from the course. By the way, the course is from the C++ institute. They claim the last code snippet is valid C++, but I don't understand it :-(

Comment: The `x` in `Y(int x)` is the name of the constructor's parameter. Whatever argument you pass to `Y` when constructing an instance can be referred to by the name `x`. The `x` in the `: x(1)` part refers to the data member named `x` that `Y` contains. I have no idea what this quoted section *We should also add ...* is talking about.

Comment: @T.C. So you mean it is another constructor of Y; some sort of a complement to make sure x can be instantiated ? Or does Y have two constructors? One of them should be erroneous because x has to have a parameter for the constructor, right?

Comment: @Elyasin there is only one constructor for `Y`. It is *declared* in the class body and *defined* later. The choice of `x` for the parameter name is a bad choice since it will hide the member `x` in the *body* of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got it. Now I feel it was a stupid question, but for some reason I was thinking invocation/construction and not declaration. I'm happy with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second code snippet, there is no construction actually going on—it's just a definition of the classes and constructors. The only "special" thing about it is that the body of `Y`'s constructor is defined outside the class; it could be in a different file, for example. In this case, it's no different from putting the body directly into the class<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Y {
       X x;
public:
      Y(int x) : x(1) {}
};
```

When this constructor of `Y` is invoked, it constructs the member variable `x` by passing `1` to the `X` constructor taking `int`. The constructor of `Y` doesn't do anything else, i.e. it ignores its own parameter.

The syntax `Y::Y` used in the original code snippet is standard syntax for defining a member function outside of the class definition. For a non-constructor, it would look like this:

```
class Foo
{
  int bar() const;
};

int Foo::bar() const
{
  return 42;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> With the slight difference that when put directly into the class definition, the function is implicitly `inline` (can be present in more than one translation unit).

Comment: @T.C. True, edited in. I just felt this was probably above the OP's level.